# Team QLOGIC iSCSI HBA 4052c

Tags: bonding, qlogic, network-teaming

We have a dual port QLogic iSCSI HBA (QLA-4052c) and we're trying to team the two ports to allow for 2GB throughput.

The documentation seems really poor on Qlogic and we can't find any reference to teaming configuration. Does anyone know if this is even possible with this HBA?

We've tried looking through SANSurfer and the QLogic CLI but again no reference to teaming the two ports. The HBA is in a Windows Server 2000 (SP4 x86) box if that makes any difference.

Any advice would be kindly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't team iSCSI, you have to use MPIO. Also, both ends will have to support MPIO. So both the server (initiator) and the SAN (target) will need to support the configuration. Different targets get configured for MPIO differently, so consult your documentation. In particular I know some target require you to specify each MPIO connection to a different IP manually, while others use a single IP and something akin to teaming.

MPIO support for Win2K is wretched, you're long past due to upgrade. But if you insist, you'll want the [iSCSI Initiator 2.08](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18986) and it's corresponding [Users Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/e/9/ae91dea1-66d9-417c-ade4-92d824b871af/uguide.doc)